# AWS CLI filter to return unique list of the latests AMIs for a particular AMI name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, amazon-ami

I'd like to use the AWS CLI to unique list containing only the most recent AMI names

This is my current command, which returns multiple AMI names for each service:

```
aws ec2 describe-images --owners "<ACCOUNT_ID>" --filters "Name=name,Values=${ami_name}*"  --query 'reverse(sort_by(Images, &CreationDate))[*].Name' --output table
```

Example output:

```
-------------------------------------------
|             DescribeImages              |
+-----------------------------------------+
|  service_abc_500 (latest)               |
|  service_xyz_350 (latest)               |
|  service_abc_499                        |
|  service_abc_498                        |
|  service_xyz_349                        |
```

Desired output:

```
-------------------------------------------
|             DescribeImages              |
+-----------------------------------------+
|  service_abc_500                        |
|  service_xyz_350                        |
```

AMI names for a given service will always the same prefix, the only difference would be the unique ID appended to the end of the AMI name, i.e. `_500`, `_350`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `[-1]` instead of `[*]` in your query to retrieve just the latest item. See: [How to filter the output with the --query option](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-output.html)

Heres the example given in the docs:

> The following example retrieves a list of images that meet several
> criteria. It then uses the --query parameter to sort the output by
> CreationDate, selecting only the most recent. Finally, it displays the
> ImageId of that one image.

```
$ aws ec2 describe-images \
    --owners amazon \
    --filters "Name=name,Values=amzn*gp2" "Name=virtualization-type,Values=hvm" "Name=root-device-type,Values=ebs" \
    --query "sort_by(Images, &CreationDate)[-1].ImageId" \
    --output text
```

`ami-00ced3122871a4921`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, this isn't quite what I was looking for. I'm already able to fetch the most recent AMI, but I'm looking to fetch the most recent AMIs for a set of prefixes all at once.

So rather than just returning the single most recent AMI, I'd like to fetch the most recent AMIs for:

service_1,
service_2,
service_3

all at once. It seems at this point it might be easier to create a script that will run this command X amount of times for each prefix I'm looking for.

Thanks again!

Comment: As you say a script with a loop for each service would work. Slightly different approach, could you add a Tag to the latest version of each AMI, then just pull back all AMIs with said tag?

Comment: That could definitely work, and might actually make things easier in the long run as new services are added.